# Can not scroll to row at index path in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to scroll to index path when I click on collection view cell in a different view, with the help of observer pattern with notification, and get exception that my bound for row and section are 0 (while the table IS populated properly).

```
func selectedDay(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! [String: AnyObject]
    let selectedDayIndex = userInfo["selectedDayIndex"] as! Int?

    if let selectedDay = selectedDayIndex {
        print("YES: \(selectedDay)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.scrollToRow(selectedDay)
        }
}


func scrollToRow(section: Int) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: section)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
}
```

I am able to print the index I am getting from the notification, and my table is populated like this: 
[image]

I understand that my table seems to be empty, when accessing it from this method. I do have proper delegate, data source connections. 
This is my log:
[image]

cell for row at index is loaded from the array, that is fetched with completion block, and table.reloadData() on return of boolean true:
[image]

Comment: Looks like your model has been released. How are you loading the cells for index path?

Comment: i load them from array, see updated question.

Comment: How is meetings declared? Is the table view on screen when the tap is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: section)
```

assumes there is an object at meetings[0][section]. You should say:

```
func scrollToRow(section: Int) {
if(meetings.count > 0 && meetings[section].count > 0)
{
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: section)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
}else{
    print("there is no section: \(section)")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just simple check helped, because indeed some of the sections were not populated:

```
func scrollToRow(section: Int) {
    if(meetings.count > 0 && meetings[section].count > 0)
    {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: section)
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
    }else{
        print("there is no section: \(section)")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, can you edit your answer? I will accept it immediately!